# location of uploaded xml file in wordpress

Tags: xml, wordpress, file-structure

I'm trying to find my demo content.XML that I uploaded via the import plugin for WordPress my developer ran away with all the files and i just need the demo content to rebuild the site.

Does anyone know if or where the uploaded XML file is saved on my server - i have the theme and i have ftp and Cpanel access just no xml content to upload - and theme forest will not give me access as the account was in his name understandably.

I have checked all the upload folders to no avail in wp-content>uploads

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: It doesn't keep it around...It runs the import and then destroys the file.

Comment: Not good news but thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/import.php#L58), WordPress doesn't keep the file. It uploads it via `wp_insert_attachment()`, does its processing, and then runs `wp_delete_attachment()`:

```
/**
 * Cleanup importer.
 *
 * Removes attachment based on ID.
 *
 * @since 2.0.0
 *
 * @param string $id Importer ID.
 */
function wp_import_cleanup( $id ) {
    wp_delete_attachment( $id );
}
```

View the full source of the importer [on GitHub](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-admin/includes/import.php#L58).